# Python multiprocessing pool does not processing all items from the list

Tags: concurrency, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I have the following program where I'm performing multiprocess.pool().
I'm passing a list of testzones for which the processes has to run.
Testzone list contains 134 values i.e., 1 - 134 and for each and every value it has to process the data and generate result.

When I'm making multiprocess.pool value as 20 it is not running the code for all the values from list. It is leaving lot of values from the list and running the code only for 60% of values and ending the code without any error.
Where as when I'm making the multiprocess.pool(30) as 30 it is able to start the process for all the values from the list. But due to high concurrency, all the machine memory is getting filled and my process is getting fail, so I cannot make it 30. I have to run it with less concurrency somewhere about 20 - 24.

I have included the logging and I can see it's starting the child process as below:

```
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-14] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-16] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-17] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-18] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-19] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-20] child process calling self.run()
```

but even after starting childprocess it is not running for all the values, I'm cheking the same using logs:

```
Line 44: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:12,657:main:Running it for:2
Line 45: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:12,752:main:Running it for:52
Line 46: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:12,672:main:Running it for:34
Line 47: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:12,673:main:Running it for:12
Line 48: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:12,660:main:Running it for:30
Line 61: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:13,175:main:Running it for:41
Line 84: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:13,260:main:Running it for:10
Line 220: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:13,371:main:Running it for:56
Line 328: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:13,640:main:Running it for:23
Line 329: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:13,443:main:Running it for:54
Line 356: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:13,726:main:Running it for:14
Line 391: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:13,871:main:Running it for:25
Line 464: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:13,530:main:Running it for:27
Line 486: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:14,086:main:Running it for:5
Line 528: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:14,776:main:Running it for:48
Line 658: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:15,069:main:Running it for:43
Line 661: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:14,959:main:Running it for:21
Line 730: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:14,308:main:Running it for:46
Line 911: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:14,455:main:Running it for:29
Line 912: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:15,518:main:Running it for:32
Line 959: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:15,164:main:Running it for:16
Line 1080: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:15,612:main:Running it for:18
Line 2443: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:32,313:main:Running it for:6
Line 2453: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:30,072:main:Running it for:58
Line 2525: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:33,272:main:Running it for:61
Line 2862: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:37,937:main:Running it for:63
Line 3006: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:38,208:main:Running it for:65
Line 3119: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:38,486:main:Running it for:69
Line 3124: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:38,327:main:Running it for:67
Line 3146: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:38,829:main:Running it for:70
Line 3656: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:40,235:main:Running it for:72
Line 3942: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:58,542:main:Running it for:74
Line 3989: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,169:main:Running it for:8
Line 4007: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:58,737:main:Running it for:76
Line 4063: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,741:main:Running it for:85
Line 4086: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,870:main:Running it for:89
Line 4123: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,059:main:Running it for:102
Line 4124: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,093:main:Running it for:105
Line 4125: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,877:main:Running it for:95
Line 4126: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:58,905:main:Running it for:78
Line 4131: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,986:main:Running it for:96
Line 4132: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,767:main:Running it for:87
Line 4133: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,556:main:Running it for:83
Line 4234: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,509:main:Running it for:108
Line 4257: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,535:main:Running it for:112
Line 4289: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,999:main:Running it for:44
Line 4305: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,516:main:Running it for:110
Line 4337: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,660:main:Running it for:117
Line 4340: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,911:main:Running it for:122
Line 4377: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:57:59,465:main:Running it for:81
Line 4493: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,685:main:Running it for:119
Line 4745: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:01,387:main:Running it for:125
Line 4779: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:00,638:main:Running it for:114
Line 6069: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:03,433:main:Running it for:127
Line 6664: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:16,081:main:Running it for:129
Line 6822: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:23,421:main:Running it for:131
Line 6949: [INFO]2020-06-22 20:58:27,839:main:Running it for:134
```

skipping lots of value from the list which is between 1 to 134 and running the process randomly starting with 2, 52. 34. 12 and running the process for above shown list values and leaving. also at the end the process is finishing without any error.

```
def run_multiprocess(self):

    num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    logger.debug("Number of avilable cores***** :- " + str(num_processes))
    df_fin = pd.read_csv('data/df_fin.csv')
    testzone_list = self.df_fin['TEST_ZONE_ID'].unique().tolist()
    testzone_list = list(d[str(df_fin['CAT_NBR'][0])])'''
    logger.debug("Number of available prizones : - " )
    logger.debug(testzone_list)
    mylog = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    mylog.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(24)
    r = pool.map_async(self.run, testzone_list)
    r.wait()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Does someone faced same kind of issue or can help me here to get into the root cause. Is there is anyway to debugg this?

Comment: What is the length of the result you get back? Is it the same as the length of `testzone_list`? `map`/`map_async` breaks your iterable into chunks, and passes the chunks to each worker, so it's expected to see them processed out of order.

Comment: Yes, it should run the process for all the values in testzone_list and return the result for each and eveyone, but same is not happening. Seems currently when the pool value is less it's running for everyone. Leaving some of them in between. Yes it is procssing out of order with map and map_async. Is there is a way I can make it in order and run for all the values in my list i.e., testzone_list ?

Comment: It should be same as the length of testzone_list. Any alternative for map /  map_async

Comment: Use `imap` to avoid the chunking. EDIT: Or use `map`/`map_async` with `chunksize=1`.

Comment: First you compute `df_fin`. Then in the next line you reference `self.df_fin['TEST_ZONE_ID'].unique().tolist()` and assign it to `testzone.list` (what is `self.df_fin`?) and then in the very next line you clobber `testzone.list` with a statement that ends with an improbable `'''`. Are we really seeing the correct source and enough of it to figure out what is going on?